# HTML - Audio file works if I open index file but will not when uploaded to web

Tags: html, audio

I added a short sound clip to my Webpage, and when I open the page directly from the index file, the 15 second sound clip is there. I then uploaded it through Filezilla (several times) and when I open through the web, the sound bar shows 0 seconds. It just doesn't make sense to me. Is there something wrong with my HTML code? Thanks in advance.

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="keleigreeting.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="keleigreeting.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<a href="audio/keleigreeting.m4a">Welcome to keleigrace designs!</a>
</audio>
```

Comment: Probably file isn't linked correctly. What exactly do you mean by "index file"? Locally?

Answer (score 0):

Is the audio file uploaded to the correct folder? You have two references
audio/keleigreeting.m4a and just keleigreeting.m4a

Try changing

```
<source src="keleigreeting.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
```

to

```
<source src="audio/keleigreeting.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
```